# Get automatically offline copy of Google docs in Windows, Mac and Linux

Tags: google-docs

I am using Google Docs. I would like to have offline copies of my documents on my different machines—Mac, Windows and Linux—that are updated automatically. Do you know of any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to be able to edit Google Docs through your browser while offline, [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) supports this.  [This page](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92254) has information about what features are supported specifically.

Unfortunately Google Gears is not yet supported for the Linux or Mac versions of Chrome, but it is supported by Firefox on Mac, Windows, and Linux.

Comment: Note that [Gears is deprecated and will no longer be available as of December 2011](http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/stopping-gears.html).