# How to synchronize SugarSync and Google Docs automatically?

Tags: google-docs, sugarsync

I would like to be able to edit one of my SugarSync files directly from a Google Docs interface and save it online directly to SugarSync (and then be able to go back to my home computer and have the file already synced to my computer).

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get automatically offline copy of google docs in win, mac and linux](http://superuser.com/questions/141966/get-automatically-offline-copy-of-google-docs-in-win-mac-and-linux), but cannot be closed because of the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You could pull something like that off using cloud-to-cloud-sync or desktop-to-cloud-sync services.

An example for Cloud-to-cloud is [CloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/sugarsync). It starts from $ 4.90 a month..

If you want a syncing app that makes your Google document available for editing locally, you should take a look at [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/). Use SugarSync to sync the Google Drive folder (which is in your InSync folder) your document is in. I frankly don't see the point of doing that, but it is a solution. InSync is currently free because it is in Beta.

Installing Google Drive is not a solution because the Google Docs are not saved locally for editing but are represented as a link to your online account. This is the same reason why you cannot use [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/): It would only sync a URL shortcut.

Comment: There is a Google Docs desktop client now.